# where to use generated shared secret in in app puschase in iphone sdk?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

The 32 bit new shared secret has been generated for my in app purchase,In this link ( https://itunesconnect.apple.com/docs/iTunesConnect_DeveloperGuide.pdf ) go to

Managing in app purchase----->Creating subscriptions------->Read point no.4.as suggested here i have 32 bit shared secret but where to use it i have no idea.I am not clear with point no.7 in the above link.

( The new shared secret that has been generated can now be used when you make the call to our servers for your In-App Purchase receipts.)

Answer (score 1):

> Only used for iOS 6 style transaction receipts for auto-renewable
>   subscriptions. Your app’s shared secret (a hexadecimal string).

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/General/ValidateAppStoreReceipt/Chapters/ValidateRemotely.html